# How to configure a multistep webform with custom alias to use GET instead of POST

Tags: webforms

I have a multi step webform, which I'm using as a kind of configurator. I want to allow people to share the link, so they can land on the last page of teh form with all the other values already set.

I configured a **custom path** (people will ask for a nice url instead of the default one)

I configured **GET (custom)** und Webform > Settings > Form > Form Custom Settings

I'm forced there to enter a submission url, so I entered the same url as for the custom path.

The issue is now, that I'm stuck on the first page - a lot of params are added to the url, but I'm not getting to page 2.

If I use a different submit url, then the forms on I land on a 404 page.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I opened https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3401813 to address this issue

Comment: Answer from the maintainer: "GET will never work with multistep because the form data is tracked via the POST" - I asked for a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the maintainer was very clear, that he will [not support GET in a multistep webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3401813). In order to still realise our requirements I had to become creative:

- multistep webform for the configuration process (dissabled submit button)
- on the last page I added a custom link via the "computed twig" form element which leads to a view with exposed filters

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{path('view.viewId.pageId', {arg_0: data.state, title: data.title, other_field: data.other_field})}}">link text</a>
```

- the view has then a context filter (arg_0) and exposed filters, which correspond with the parameters from the link. The exposed filter itself is configured to be a block ,so it is not shown.

It works pretty well, and if you choose the urls right, the flow is frictionless

In case it helps somebody else :fingers_crossed: